# How do I map Lock Screen to "Super+L" i.e. Win+L?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I want to map my <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> so that when I press the combination my screen is locked. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open System Settings, click on Keyboard > Shortcuts > System. There you should find the shortcut for "Lock screen" (or similar). Click on the default value (Ctrl+Alt+L), then press your key combination.